# Pnl Explanation using R (blotter)

Tags: programming

I have a portfolio of stocks based on a proprietary strategy. I would like to explain the Pnl over a period, for example I would like to find the pnl contribution of each name of the period. 
Is there function/package for that please?

Comment: Enrico Schumann's R package PMwR has some capabilities for analyzing a trade blotter. I don't know the details.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that is a start, I will have a look and navigate from there

Comment: @noob2: thank you for suggesting `PMwR` . @Franky Doul: You have
not said what exactly your "portfolio" is, but since
you mentioned a blotter, I suppose you have a list of
trades.  The most time-consuming task is usually to
move from the list of trades to the P/L, and this is
where `PMwR` offers some tools. For then analysing the P/L, you can use all the tools that R offers (or any other tool). I tried
to write up a short tutorial for computing P/L with
`PMwR`: http://enricoschumann.net/notes/computing-portfolio-pl.html . (It is probably too long to post as an answer here.)

Comment: Hi @EnricoSchumann, Yes indeed, I have a list of trades, created using the blotter package, and a Journal as well. Let me check your article.